# How to drop single valued columns effiecently from dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

How to drop all columns which have single value from a dataframe effiecntly ?

I found two ways:

This method ignores **null** and only considers other values, I need to consider nulls in my case

```
# apply countDistinct on each column
col_counts = partsDF.agg(*(countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c) for c in partsDF.columns)).collect()[0].asDict()
```

this method takes too long time

```
col_counts = partsDF.agg(*(   partsDF.select(c).distinct().count() for c in partsDF.columns)).collect()[0].asDict()

#select the cols with count=1 in an array
cols_to_drop = [col for col in partsDF.columns if col_counts[col] == 1 ]
```

Comment: This is just not what spark is designed to do, so there isn't going to be a really good way to do it. Try to see if the following is better for you: `col_counts = partsDF.agg(*([when(((countDistinct(c)==1)|(count(c)==0)), 1).otherwise(0) for c in partsDF.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()` (where `when`, `count`, and `countDistinct` are imported from `pyspark,sql.functions`

Comment: @pault, thanks for your answer, am trying to modify your code to suit me, what am trying to do is more like 
`col_counts = partsDF.agg(*([when((partsDF.select(c).distinct().count()>1), 1).otherwise(0).alias(c) for c in partsDF.columns])).collect()[0].asDict()`

but this one throws  `TypeError: condition should be a Column`